# Do MySQL views ever expire?

Tags: mysql, view

Do MySQL views ever expire or get automatically deleted?

It looks like temporary tables only last as long as the connection.  Do views have a similar expiration date?

If Apache or MySQL is restarted, will the views get dropped?

Right now, it looks like views only get deleted if I manually drop them (or overwrite them with new data).

I looked on MySQL documentation, Google and SO but could not find any discussion on this.

Answer (score 3):

Temporary tables are automatically deleted only because they are **temporary**.

Views are not temporary, so they aren't automatically deleted.

Comment: If MySQL server is restarted, do views remain intact?